# Facebook PHP Sdk Access Token

Tags: php, facebook, sdk

I know there are tons of topics

on this question, but every single one that I've seen, seems to have no solution at all!
I'm getting the infamous "Oauth Exception - An active access token must be used to query information about the current user" and I don't know what to do.

My facebook connect was working perfectly fine until yesterday, now, it stopped working all of a sudden today.

Can anyone please help me with this?
I'm using php sdk to connect the user to facebook in a pop-up window, then I make him autorize my app and redirect the window to a php called facebookReturn.php.
In this file, I'm supposed to get the user info, save it on Session, then close the window and refresh the main page behind.

Here are my codes.

index.php:

```
require_once 'phps/facebook.php';

$config = array();
$config[appId] = 'xxxx';
$config[secret] = 'xxxx';
$config[fileUpload] = false;
$facebook = new Facebook ($config);

$facebookId = $facebook->getUser();
echo "<br>facebook id: $facebookId";

if ($facebookId) {
    $userProfile = $facebook->api('/me');
    $logoutUrl = $facebook->getLogoutUrl();
}
else {
    $params = array ();
    $params[scope] = 'publish_stream, user_birthday, email, user_activities';
    $params[redirect_uri] = 'http://www.mydomain.com.br/phps/facebookReturn.php';
    $params[display] = 'popup';
    $loginUrl = $facebook->getLoginUrl($params);
}
```

facebookReturn.php:

```
require_once 'facebook.php';
$config = array();
$config[appId] = 'xxxx';
$config[secret] = 'xxxx';
$config[fileUpload] = false;
$facebook = new Facebook ($config);

$user = $facebook->getUser();
$userProfile = $facebook->api('/me');
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Which line and file are you getting this error ?

Comment: You don't appear to be getting an `access_token` anywhere. Facebook redirects the user back to your return page with an authorization code. It's up to you to the exchange that for a token.

Comment: I get this error right here:
$userProfile = $facebook->api('/me');

When I try to get the user info.

Colin, I never needed an access token, it was working fine yesterday. What should I do?

Answer (score 1):

Remomber: Facebook token expires in 60 days.